# Ambiguity in question, isn't written whether distance along boundary is required or direct distance

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, quadratics

Question: A pole has to be erected at a point on the boundary of a circular park of diameter 13 meter in such a way that difference of its distances from two diametrically opposite fixed gates A and B on the boundary is 7 meter. Is it possible? If yes, at what distances from the two gates should the pole be?

Approach 1: let P be pole and A and B gates on either sides. Joining AB forms a semicircle thus angle APB = 90deg. By setting up a quadratic and solving

Approach 2: let P be pole and A and B gates on either sides. Given diameter = 13m curved length of semicircle is 6.5π meter now assuming arc(AP) > arc(PB) setting up a system of L.E. and solving them  
x - y = 7
x + y = 6.5π

Which method was implied by the question or are both equivalent

Comment: Where was the Question given ? What was the Answer ? That will give the Detail on which Interpretation is the Assumption. Without knowing that : Both are Possible , though **"Straight line Distance" is very Common & Implicit** , unless the "Curved Distance" is Explicitly given !

Comment: Both interpretations seem reasonable. If you made your interpretation clear I would give you full marks for either.

Comment: @Paul I believe my answer which I have written in the answer sheet was reasoned out well but my the teacher still doesn't agree on crediting the 2nd approach. I believe that both the answers are equivalent since the arc length and and chord are related with each other, rigth?

Comment: @Prem The question was asked in our class 10 term exams.
I'd like to frame an equivalent question, suppose, A is running in a circular track and he is 10 meter from the winning pole, it surely implies that the pole is on the track however if it were to be 'between' then one could say that the pole is on any point which lies on the circumference of the circle drawn with A as centre and 10 meter as radius. 
Both this and the above question can be thought about with similar logic.

Answer (score 0):

I was typing a long Comment , which exceeded the Character limit , hence Posting this Answer , to aid OP.

**[[A]]** Interpretations 1 & 2 : Both are Possible , though "Straight line Distance" is very Common & Implicit , unless the "Curved Distance" is Explicitly given.

**[[B]]** Here are my "Equivalent Questions" which will show that Straight line or Curve may make more sense :
(B1) "Instead of Pole , think you have to stand there & throw a Ball. One Gate requires 7m more than the Other"
(B2) "Instead of Circular race , you are in a Circular merry-go-round. One Partner is much ahead of you. The Other Partner is much behind you & 7m more. You have to throw a toy to Both"
In these 2 Cases , will you use the Curve (Arc) or the Straight line (Chord) to measure along ? Straight makes more sense.
(B3) You have to make Wooden wall & Metal wall around the Park. Wooden wall is 7m more than Metal wall.
(B4) You have to Paint the wall around the Park. White wall is 7 times the Green wall.
In these 2 Cases , will you use the Curve (Arc) or the Straight line (Chord) to measure along ? Curve makes more sense.

**[[C]]** Is Straight line (Chord) Solution Equivalent to Curve (Arc) Solution ?
Certain Cases it will be Equivalent , though not here.
Eg : When we have Distance is "one-seventh" less , or 7 times more ( **Proportionally** less or **Proportionally** more ) , then : Both are Equivalent.
When we have Distance is less by 7m or more by 7m ( **Absolutely** less or **Absolutely** more ) , it is not Proportionally varying , hence Both are not Equivalent.

In other words , Proportionally varying Case is when we can Zoom-In or Zoom-Out (Scaling) the Circle & then the ratios will be Constant. Arc length & Chord length may be used Equivalently & Interchangeably.
Absolute Distance will vary & will not be Equivalent.

**[[D]]** Solving your Question :

**Method 1 (which is Common & which your teacher is asking) :**
$x^2+(x+7)^2=13^2$ , which gives $2x^2+14x+49=169$
$x^2+7x-60=0$
$x \approx 4.97$

Scale the Circle to Double Size , we will get :
$x^2+(x+7)^2=26^2$ & $x \approx 4.97$ will not work , because 7 is Absolute Change , not Proportional Change.

**Method 2 (which is valid, though not which your teacher is asking) :**
Semi-Circle Arc length is $\pi 13 /2$
$x+(x+7)=13\pi$ which gives $2x = \pi 13 /2 - 7$
$x \approx 13.42$
Not Equivalent.